# Specifying fields in Django's DetailView

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way to use the convenient `{{ form.as_ul }}` functionality but then with `DetailView`, something like `{{ object.as_ul }}`?

In other words, I'm looking for a DetailView that would populate itself with the `field`s provided in the views.py. 
This would avoid typing all fields of the model manually (like `{{ object.first_name }}`, `{{ object.last_name }}`, `{{ object.address_street }}`, `{{ object.address_city }}`, etc.) in the template.

Is this easily possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this the "right way," so I'm going to tell you how I would do it. That will get you started until someone else can post a better answer.

```
def as_ul(self):
    t = Template('<ul>{% for i in items %}<li>{{ i }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>')
    c = Context({'items': [getattr(self, x.name) for x in self._meta.fields]})
    return t.render(c)
```

You'll probably want to modify that a bit to filter out certain field names (such as 'id').